# Add incremental count to unique values of SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this is a little bit difficult for me to explain in words, so I apologize if the Title doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  What I want to do is to make a query and grab unique combinations from a table with a common value and append an incremental count to those values.

So if I had a table like so:

```
id | name | loc1  | loc2

1  | Fred | USA   |
2  | Fred |       | Spain
3  | Fred |       | 
4  | Ryan | Canada| USA
5  | Steph| Spain | Canada
6  | Fred | USA   |
```

I would like to have a query that results in the following:

```
name   | loc1  | loc2

Fred-1 | USA   |
Fred-2 |       | Spain
Fred-3 | USA   |
Ryan-1 | Canada| USA
Steph-1| Spain | Canada
```

I can grab the unique values I want with the query:

```
select id, name, loc1, loc2 from table1 where loc1 <> '' OR loc2 <> ''
```

But appending the count number has me stumped.  I believe if I could some how use ROW_NUMBER() for each unique subquery that may work, but I don't know how to manage that one.  Note that it doesn't really matter which order they are in (i.e. it doesn't matter which row gets -1, -2, or -3 for Fred).

Any thoughts?

Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5c079/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()` inside `concat()`:

```
select 
  concat(name, '-', row_number() over (partition by name order by id)) as name, 
  loc1, loc2 
from table1
where loc1 <> '' OR loc2 <> ''
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db73371c84c4bac8dfa3ed3d30bd2b4e).
Results:

```
> name    | loc1   | loc2  
> :------ | :----- | :-----
> Fred-1  | USA    |       
> Fred-2  |        | SPAIN 
> Fred-3  | USA    |       
> Ryan-1  | CANADA | USA   
> Steph-1 | SPAIN  | CANADA
```

Comment: Wow, that was much simpler than I thought it would be.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
select t.name + '-' + convert(varchar(150),t.rn)  from (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by id) rn from Yourtable
) t
```